# Binding list<T> from UserControl

Tags: c#, winforms

Why is the `LinkData` property from `UserControl1` not set in this code?

```
namespace UserControlBinding
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {         
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {         
            List<DEST> R = new List<DEST>();
            R.Add(new DEST() { Labels = "C:\\\\Books\\logogog.png" });
            R.Add(new DEST() { Labels = "C:\\\\Books\\121.png" });         

            userControl11.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("LinkData", R, "Labels", true)); 
        }
    }         

    public class DEST
    {
        public string Labels { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace UserControlBinding
{
    [System.ComponentModel.DefaultBindingProperty("LinkData")] // Bind UserControl
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        private List<DEST> _LinkData;

        public List<DEST> LinkData
        {
            get { return _LinkData; } // unknown ????
            set { _LinkData = value;}
        }                 
    }
}
```

Do I need to keep track of the event or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does actually work when you change your binding to:

```
userControl11.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("LinkData", R, "Labels", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
```

And your definition of `LinkData` to:

```
private string _LinkData;

public string LinkData
{
    get { return _LinkData; } // unknown ????
    set { _LinkData = value; }
}
```

This is because you bind to the `Labels` property, not the entire list.

So the solution is to change the binding to something like this:

```
var x = new { X = R };

userControl11.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("LinkData", x, "X", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
```

The `var x` part just creates an anonymous type, you can create your own class if you want to. The binding now binds to `X` of that class.